# Regex for removing leading and trailing whitepsaces from XML file

Tags: regex, xml

I have been trying to remove all the whitespace characters (including \r,\n,\t) from the XML file using the following regex:

```
    >([\r\n\t ])*([^ ]*[^<>]*[^ ]*)([\r\n\t ])*<
```

But this regex captures all the XML tags within the file as a single match. How can I improve this regex to meet the requirement?

Input String:

```
    <Address>
    <City>   New York   </City>
    <Zip> 1001 </Zip>
    </Address>
```

Expected Result (When replaced with \2):

```
    <Address>
    <City>New York</City>
    <Zip>1001</Zip>
    </Address>
```

Comment: Here is one [weird regex for this](https://regex101.com/r/6LdbDH/1).

Answer (score 1):

A regex to match the whitespaces between a `>` and a wordcharacter.
Or the whitespaces between a wordcharacter and `</`

```
(?<=[>])\s+(?=\w)|(?<=\w)\s+(?=[<]\/)
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/VuI9CZ/1)

By using the lookbehinds and lookahead, only the whitespaces are captured.

Why your original regex had issues? Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/VMiD0G/1) example, and check in the explanation what happens when you remove the `?` from the `[\w ]+?`. (greedy versus lazy)